# Google Cloud Storage -Can't get default bucket name

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I tried to get the default bucket name from the developer console:

Application Settings > Cloud Integration

but get message:

> An error occurred when creating the project. Please retry.

Also tried to get default bucket name from code:

```
AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService().getDefaultGcsBucketName();
```

and receive

```
 Uncaught exception from servlet
com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityServiceFailureException: getDefaultGcsBucketNameResponse contained no data
    at com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityServiceImpl.getDefaultGcsBucketName(AppIdentityServiceImpl.java:215)
```

Anyone have any ideas?

(Cloud Storage API  is enabled, and billing is disabled - I want try it with free quota)

Comment: Did you create the project through appengine.google.com or console.developer.google.com?

Comment: I created project throught console.developer.google.com, not foud how proect can be created throught appengine.google.com.